# Detecting Past UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a for loop which calls a class method in another class where a UIAlertView popup will trigger under certain conditions.  I want to escape the loop if the popup was shown.  What is the usual tactic for implementing this type of communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's possible to find some way to detect if some UIAlertView is exposed now.
But it's not very good. Programs build in such way may fall apart with minor changes in frameworks guts. You need some connection between objects.
1. Use delegation pattern. It's the best way.
2. If connections between objects are too complex or unpredictable which makes difficult usage of delegation, use notifications pattern (read about NSNotificationCenter class).

Answer (score 1):

If the class method shows the UIAlertView when there is an error, then it might make sense to return an error code to the caller, which can stop iterating if it gets an error code back.

Some NS methods do something like this, where you pass an NSError** to the method and if there is an error, it sets the pointer, ie:

```
NSError* error = nil;

for (id object in SomeObjects) {
    [NSDoSomething:object error:&error]; 

    if (error) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a BOOL somewhere that would be accessible by both classes. For example:

```
// declare this variable somewhere that will be accessible to both classes, i.e. a singleton
BOOL alertIsShown;

// when showing the UIAlertView:
alertView.delegate = self;
[alertView show];
alertIsShown = YES;

// UIAlertViewDelegate method
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    alertIsShown = NO;
}

// in your for loop
for(...) if(alertIsShown) break;
```